# form is not sending data using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to save data into database using code igniter .But there is a problem in sending data .Actually ,form is not sending data .I check it with print_r() .
Here is my form with controller and model.
Please check it and give me a right solution.

view

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?
>index.php/c_autoapp/insert_tech" >
<input type="text" name="f_name" >
<input type="text" name="l_name" >
<input type="text" name="user_name" >
<input type="password" name="password" >
<input type="text" name="address" >
<input type="text" name="account" >
<input type="text" name="phone" >
<input type="email" name="email" >
<input type="text" name="status" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

controller

this is my controller.

```
 function insert_tech()
    {
        $this->m->insert_tech();

    }
```

I check table name and all column names in database.These are all right.

model

```
  function insert_tech()
        {   
            if($this->input->post('submit'))
            {
            $f_name=$this->input->post('f_name');
            $l_name=$this->input->post('l_name');
            $user_name=$this->input->post('user_name');
            $password=$this->input->post('password');
            $address=$this->input->post('address');
            $account=$this->input->post('account');
            $phone=$this->input->post('phone');
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $status=$this->input->post('status');
            $arr = array('l_name'=>$l_name,
                         'f_name'=>$f_name,
                         'user_name'=>$user_name,
                         'password'=>$password,
                         'address'=>$address,
                         'account'=>$account,
                         'phone'=>$phone,
                         'email'=>$email,
                         'status'=>$status
            );
           $this->db->insert('tb_tech', $arr);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validate your `$this->input->post()` in your controller not in model

CONTROLLER

```
function insert_tech(){
       if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $f_name=$this->input->post('f_name');
            $l_name=$this->input->post('l_name');
            $user_name=$this->input->post('user_name');
            $password=$this->input->post('password');
            $address=$this->input->post('address');
            $account=$this->input->post('account');
            $phone=$this->input->post('phone');
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $status=$this->input->post('status');
            $arr = array('l_name'=>$l_name,
                         'f_name'=>$f_name,
                         'user_name'=>$user_name,
                         'password'=>$password,
                         'address'=>$address,
                         'account'=>$account,
                         'phone'=>$phone,
                         'email'=>$email,
                         'status'=>$status
            );
        $this->m->insert_tech($arr);
        }
}
```

MODEL

```
function insert_tech($arr){ 
    $this->db->insert('tb_tech', $arr);
}
```

Comment: I used print_r() function in controller .This shows blank page.

Comment: It's working on my end. have you use `print_r($this->input->post());` in first line of the controller function?

Answer (score 1):

Add __constructor function in your controller and print your post data.

```
public function __constructor()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }
public function insert_tech()
    {

        print_r($this->input->post());
    }
```

Form helper print the all post data by form.

Comment: function __construct(){

   parent::__construct();
     $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->model('M_autoapp','m');
  }

Comment: bro! this is my constructor .it is not working on my end using post method .With get method it is working well.